# css unable to move login validator

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I have two requiredfield validators in visual studio. Now I am trying to apply css to them like below:

```
#vdtrUserLogin { top:65px; left:750; position:absolute}
#vdtrPasswordLogin0 { top:65px; left:900; position:absolute}
```

However the left position does not seem to take effect. How can I fix this?

Thanks
Behrouz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `px` to your units.

```
#vdtrUserLogin { top:65px; left:750px; position:absolute}
#vdtrPasswordLogin0 { top:65px; left:900px; position:absolute}
```